# CustomProperty LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How to fetch custom properties from a failed logic app run?

I am able to fetch through output only when it's successful. Is there any way to accomplish this even when it's failed?

Comment: what do you mean by custom properties ?

Comment: Are you asking about the Run History?

Comment: Yes, I meant from a run history. Suppose I want to fetch the count of items (fetch from run output) processed in a for-each control action. I am able to get it only when the run is successful.